# What would be some social welfare systems of a first world developed nation with a GINI Index of 32.56?

Tags: alternate-history, politics, technological-development, direct-democracy

GINI is a term that is used to measure income inequality (See here for examples https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_income_equality) and is a good indication on to what kind of society there is in this regards.

32.56 is a moderate level of income inequality which would make it less than Canada (33.8) and more than France (32.4).

However I'm currently asking and wondering what kind of welfare systems would likely be prevalent in such a first world developed nation.

The characteristics of this nation are as follows:

1. Population is 100 Million
2. GDP Per Capita is $48,000
3. Density of the country is about 1000 people per square kilometer

Other facts that may help are as follows:

1. It's the sixth most powerful nation in this world overall when all things considered
2. It's a Parlimentary Democracy with a Sainte Lague proportional representation voting method and mandatory voting
3. Trade Intensity of 50% (So Very dependent on Trade)
4. Culturally a mix of central european and korean
5. Has about 50 Nuclear Weapons
6. Gets 57% of its energy from renewable sources
7. Economic Diversity of Japan

Comment: Depends upon, in part, the culture. And upon how that culture has been impacted by its industrial revolution, agricultural revolution, and other nation-shaking changes. For example, a culture that retains an active expectation of children-care-for-older-parents may see little need for universal public-funded pensions. Perhaps a bit more description of the culture would help.

Comment: Can you define how 6th most powerful is measured. GDP? Military size? Quantity of nukes? Avalable natural resouces? Total industrial production capacity? Number of cloned T-rexes?

Comment: Sorry I'll have to vtc this.. I think for rich countries like France, the subject is 100% politics and therefore opinion-based. Building e.g. a good social security net is a political choice any 1st world country could make. It is all a matter of political choice and democracy.

Comment: Done. Everyone happy now?

Comment: @Snail343 - No cloned T-rexes? 

Comment: i second @Goodies : the answer is "anything you like".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can justify many different systems.

- The per capita GDP means they have a decent "pie" to share out. That means they can afford to have some "inaccuracies" in the rules -- people getting welfare who *might* possibly find a job. But that's also psychology. Taxpayers resent it if they *perceive* some to be freeloaders, even if the bureaucracy costs more than it saves.
- What method you use for the PR distribution is *almost* completely irrelevant. Having PR means a greater chance for coalition politics rather than two-party hyperpartisanship, but the rest is fiddling on the margins.
- If properly implemented, mandatory voting becomes the opposite of voter suppression. No tricks possible to keep people away. But again, that is *almost* completely irrelevant for the outcomes. It will make a greater difference if one of the candidates did perspire during the TV duel, or got caught by the press with an inappropriate laugh.
- The population density is only an average. Still, it is highly urbanized. They could afford a system where welfare recipients have to visit their case officer every month, every week.
- A high GDP combined with the high population density *probably* means they can afford to have that many case officers, if they want to.

So they could afford a system where "just about" anybody who has no job can ask for a minimal-subsistence handout, or a system where those who can find a job is expected to find one, and only those who cannot work (health issues, caring for small kids, ...) get welfare.

A system with "working poor" on supplemental welfare could have the same GINI as a system where the poor are subsidized.

Comment: Can you edit with the new stuff?

Comment: @Snail343, I don't think the number of nuclear weapons or the renewables affect this in **any** way. A bit like asking if the color of a car affects the speed. The cultural roots might matter, but being a 'mix' again leaves much open.